# How to recognise characters of particular icon's text in TIFF image file

Tags: c#, ocr, tiff

While recognizing the characters in a TIFF image,able to read the characters by using OCR method,MODI but where as while reading specific text format, it doesn't read the exact characters and shows some unknown characters.

Suppose this is the text format in an TIFF image file, how can I read the characters clearly in the below image?

Any way to recognize and display exact characters again? [image: sample.tif]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image analysis and OCR is always kind of a soft science, since it might work on one instance and fail in another.

Can you apply some filters before performing the OCR? You might try to blur the image beforehand to soften the impact of the dotted background and then perform OCR on the image.

Comment: i did filter with adobe photoshope ,most of the characters are recognised from the tif image.How i add the same filter in C# program with out doing manually.? is there any way to do it?